# Does GIT and Gitolite supports java version 1.4.2?

Tags: git, gitolite

In my project we have a Linux - RHEL (Tikanga ) VM, where I have been tasked to install and setup  GIT and Gitolite but the major concern is VM is using very old java version - 1.4.2 and upgrading of java isn't allowed at-least for time-being.

Is there any possibility of installing GIT 1.7 (and above) and the latest gitloite version on the VM with java 1.4.2 ?

Comment: Well I don't think, git and gitolite need any java at all. git is written in C and some python modules and gitolite also does not need java.

Comment: I'd worry less about Java (since Git doesn't run in Java) and more about what C libraries you have available.  You also don't specify which version of RHEL 5 you're running, which would help a little bit in determining if you could run more modern versions of Git on the box.

Comment: @Makoto : I'm using RHEL 5.8 (64 bit)

Answer (score 1):

Git is written in C and shell scripts. And Gitolite is written in Perl. Neither uses Java, so they both don’t care at all which Java version you have.